# Is that possible to extract doc/docx file page wise in php?

Tags: php, parsing, docx, doc

I have a web form where user needs to upload a document file (doc or docx), in that file there is some formatted data on multiple each page. so I want to extract that data but I also need to know page number as well. That means I want content of each page separately, is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not in raw format, so you want this maybe to interpret the code of docx.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord Check this.

Comment: There is no function to get the current page number. The only way is to use "addPreserveText" like:
$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}.');

Comment: I dont want to create doc using php, I need content from doc page wise

Comment: you can read them but cannot get pages... there is no function. take output echo it that's all... you can break lines after interval to show as it is new page using php